# Injectivity in cohomology for round-down $\mathbb{Q}$-divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology

On toric varieties, there is a nice statement about injectivity of cohomology for $\mathbb{Q}$-Weil divisors, due to Fujino:

*Let $D$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-Weil divisor on a toric variety $X$ and let $l > 0$ be an integer such that $lD$ is integral. Then for all $p ≥ 0$ there is an injection*
$$
H^p \big(X,\mathcal{O}_X(\lfloor D \rfloor)\big) \hookrightarrow H^p \big(X,\mathcal{O}_X(lD)\big) \,.
$$
Here $\lfloor D \rfloor$ is defined by rounding down the coefficients in the divisor expansion of $D$.

Is this result specific to toric varieties? Or is there any more general statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general this is false. For an example, let $X$ be an elliptic curve, and let $p\in X$. Take $D=\frac{1}{2} p$. Then, the round down is zero, but $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\neq 0$ and $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(p))=0$.